# Yahoo fluxible "shell is not defined" on Windows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux, fluxible

The following lines in [webpack-dev-server.js](https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible/blob/master/packages/generator-fluxible/app/templates/webpack-dev-server.js) of fluxible generated app 
give an error 'shell is not defined'

```
shell.env.PORT = shell.env.PORT || 3001;
shell.exec('"./node_modules/.bin/nodemon" start.js -e js,jsx', function () {});
```

I did

```
var shell = require('child_process');

.listen(3000, function () {
    shell.env = process.env;
    shell.env.port = 3001;
    shell.exec('"./node_modules/.bin/nodemon" start.js -e js,jsx', function () {});
    console.log('Webpack Dev Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

After the changes, the server started without the error, but still auto restart on changes doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the generator that I will fix.

In your code change the first line to `var shell = require('shelljs');` and see if that fixes it for you.